# Map/Reduce Operation on Mongoid Criteria in version 2

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

am I correct in that MongoDB map/reduce feature is not available on Mongoid Criteria for MongoId version 2+

Can any one confirm this I have a criteria

Here my Query

```
class PerformerSource
  scope :active_performers,where(:active => true).only([:performer_id, :sort_order,:stage_name, :photo, :large_photo, :status, :current_performance_type,:current_sign_in_at])
end
```

`PerformerSource.active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc])`

I want to apply map/reduce function to it

something like this

```
PerformerSource.active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc]).map_reduce(PerformerSource.map,PerformerSource.reduce)
```

but whenever I do this it return with error

**NoMethodError: undefined method `map_reduce' for #**

Checking if the map/reduce is available at all

```
PerformerSource.active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc]).respond_to?(:map_reduce)
=> false

PerformerSource.respond_to?(:map_reduce)
=> false
```

So am I correct in my believe since I see Mongoid-3 has a provision of adding map/reduce in Mongoid-criteria over [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce) but cant find the same in mongoid 2

I can upgrade mongoid (I wish I could) since the application is running on Ruby-1.8.7 and mongoid 3 required ruby-1.9+

So can let me if the map/reduce wont work on criteria how to run the map/reduce then taking the other conditions in account i.e 
`active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc])`

Note: I just for clarity in haven't added the **map** and **reduce** function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have produced the following monkey patch, which I'm using in production:

```
module Mongoid

  module Criterion #:nodoc:
    module MapReduce
      def map_reduce(map, reduce, options = {})
        opts = {:out => {:inline => 1}, :raw => true, :query => selector}.merge(options)
        klass.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, opts)
      end
      alias :mapreduce :map_reduce
    end
  end

end
```

This way I can execute map-reduce on a criteria. And if you want to execute it on *all*, then either use .all or .scoped (which I prefer), like PerformerSource.scoped.map_reduce(..)

Comment: I doubt it will fire a based on the criteria append to it like `Performer.active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc]).map_reduce' correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I didn't really understand what you have said here. BTW, the order really makes little sense unless you limit the number of results.

Comment: I said you are appending a map reduce function what will `klass.collection` would return the result `Performer.active_performers.order_by([:sort_order,:desc])` of the criteria that define and then operate map-reduce on it further the criteria after map_reduce will that work

Comment: klass.collection.map_reduce receives the original selector as a :query parameter.